# GetProcAddress does not work propely

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I want to set up a global hook and I'm having problems with getting the address of my hook procedure from the dll I created.

I've read on stackoverflow that the problem may be caused by name mangling. And in order to eliminate that problem, you have to wrap your export functions in your future dll with `extern "C"`, which I did. However, that did not help.

Here's my program:

Main.cpp

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    HHOOK hHookKeyboard;
    HINSTANCE keyboardProcDLL;
    HOOKPROC hookProcKeyboard;

    keyboardProcDLL = LoadLibrary(L"C:/PV_KeyboardDLL.dll");
    if (keyboardProcDLL == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load library!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    hookProcKeyboard = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(keyboardProcDLL, "PV_KeyboardProc");
    if (hHookKeyboard == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load function from library!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    hHookKeyboard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProcKeyboard, keyboardProcDLL, 0);

    while (1)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

PV_KeyboardDLL.cpp

```
bool toggleOnOff = false; // off by default


template<typename Type>
inline bool highOrderBit(Type value)
{
    return (value & (1 << sizeof(Type) * 8 - 1));
}

template<typename Type>
inline bool lowOrderBit(Type value)
{
    return (value & 1);
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK PV_KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        // process event
        if (nCode < 0)  // do not process message 
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        if (wParam != WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* KeyBoardHookStruct = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);

        DWORD keyCode = KeyBoardHookStruct->vkCode;

        bool ctrlDown, altDown;

        // high-order is 1 - DOWN
        ctrlDown = highOrderBit(GetKeyState(VK_LCONTROL));
        altDown = highOrderBit(GetKeyState(VK_MENU));

        // ctrl + alt + 1(key down)
        if (ctrlDown && altDown && (keyCode == 0x31))
        {
            // toggle bool
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Workin", L"Ok", MB_OK);

            toggleOnOff = !toggleOnOff;
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) bool onOrOff()
    {
        return toggleOnOff;
    }
}
```

I can load the dll, but after the call to `GetProcAddress()`, `hookProcKeyboard` is `NULL`.

I'm new to WINAPI, and I'm kind of stuck, so help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `GetProcAddress(keyboardProcDLL, "_PV_KeyboardProc");` or see the DLL exports (names) with a tool like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Comment: "_PV_KeyboardProc@12" realy exported. need call GetProcAddress for this name

Comment: Tried `_PV_KeyboardProc` and `_PV_KeyboardProc@12`, still nothing

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` exports the decorated name, which is not recommended. You should use a DEF file to export the undecorated name.

Comment: simply search in dll `PV_KeyboardProc` this name - for view in which form it here. and of course the best use def file. you can even export it by ordinal only - `PV_KeyboardProc @1 NONAME PRIVATE`

Comment: @RaymondChen, thanks, I'll try using DEF files.

Comment: @MichaelNaifield - anyway `PV_KeyboardProc` must be exported in form `_PV_KeyboardProc@12` for x86 and `PV_KeyboardProc` for x64. before move to def file - be good (for you) understand in what error now

Comment: GetProcAddress works correctly. Defect is in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a small (but important!) typo here:

```
hookProcKeyboard = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(keyboardProcDLL, "PV_KeyboardProc");
if (hHookKeyboard == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not load function from library!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    return -1;
}
```

You're calling `GetProcAddress`() to populate `hookProcKeyboard`, then checking the value of `hHookKeyboard`.  `hookProcKeyboard` will definitely be `NULL`!

Reconcile that issue and you should be closer to resolving the issue...